# What exactly is &$this referring to in PHP?

Tags: php, this, pass-by-reference

```
class ClassOne 
{
    private $foo = null;

    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->foo = new ClassTwo();
    }

    public function doStuff() 
    {
        $bar = &$this->foo->someVariable;
    }
}
```

I know that `$this` refers to the current object, and `&` is a reference symbol for changing the original variable.

What is `&$this` referring to?

Comment: if `$bar = &$foo` makes sense to you, why would `$bar = &$this` be any different?

Comment: Note that the `&` applies to everything at the right of it, so it gives a reference to `$this->foo->someMethod`, not `$this`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? You are storing a reference to `$this->foo->someMethod` in `$bar` and I wonder what you are not understanding about that.

Comment: And that's not pass-by-reference that is assigning a reference.

Comment: thanks @k0pernikus. It was actually "someVariable" not "someMethod" Why would a reference like this ever be needed? I'm trying to understand some old code someone wrote back in 2004.

Comment: I think you may have removed too much when creating your generic example here for us to really see why it does it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @k0pernikus and @trincot for clarifying that `&` refers to the entire `$this->foo->someVariable`

So the original author wanted to change `someVariable` in `$this->foo->someVariable`. Since it was verbose, he assigned the reference to `$bar`.

However, this was done in PHP4. There must be a better way to write this in PHP5.

Comment: If `$someVariable` holds an object then the reference is not needed (and not even useful). Otherwise, there is no better way to write it in PHP 5 or PHP 7.